# NSTimeZoneNameStyleShortStandard is not working iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

hi i have to show the timzone in `NSTimeZoneNameStyleShortStandard` form like IST,MST etc but i am not able to get this below is my code.o/p is coming like that `GMT+05:30` instead of `IST`.

```
NSTimeZone *systimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    NSString *timeZoneString = [systimeZone localizedName:NSTimeZoneNameStyleShortStandard locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    if([systimeZone isDaylightSavingTimeForDate:[NSDate date]]){
        timeZoneString = [systimeZone localizedName:NSTimeZoneNameStyleShortDaylightSaving locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    }
 NSLog(@"%@",timeZoneString);
```

o/p 2013-04-27 04:41:01.679 DJProject[1460:c07] GMT+05:30

Comment: Sentences. Punctuation. Upper/Lower case. Spelling. … People are not going to read crappy text.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `[NSLocale currentLocale]` hence it shows your current device locale.

Comment: @Paras what should i do as i need my current device time zone.

Comment: @parvind [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] this will return your local device timezone.